# Is there a way to save all global variables to a text file?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

There is a console command,

```
showglobalvars
```

that shows all global variables. Instead of getting that displayed in a console I want the output to be written in a text file.

I've heard about the command

```
SetConsoleOutputFilename
```

However, it doesn't work properly, since using

```
scof "c:\temp\output.txt"
```

will output

```
SetConsoleOutputFilename  >>  "c:\temp\output.txt"
```

but no such file is created.

How do I successfully print all global variables in a text file?

Comment: Does this help? http://www.gamesas.com/setconsoleouputfile-help-t255624.html

Comment: I read that and it seems he failed. I tried and fail too. Some says I can do it in CK but that will be too difficult

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish by printing all global variables? Do you want to save and load them somehow, or are you trying to do something else entirely?

Comment: Just want to see all the global variables are. Help me understand save games.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the comments, you indicate that you "just want to see [what] all the global variables are." In general, the easiest way to do this is to open the various ESP/ESM files in [xEdit](http://tes5edit.github.io/), which is a third-party modding tool. Although it is designed for modifying these files, it will give a very prominent warning before it actually lets you change anything, so it's perfectly usable as a viewer as well.

Once you've loaded Skyrim.esm and the DLC into xEdit, you can expand each of the ESP/ESM files in the panel on the left, which will show a list of categories. Expanding a category shows a list of individual records:

[image: Screenshot of the xEdit interface.]

This image is showing Fallout 3, but the same app also works on Skyrim's plugin files. Under the "Global Variables" category, there will be one record for each global variable. Clicking a record will display it in the area to the right of the navigation tree. For a global variable, it will tell you the name of that variable and the value it has at the start of the game. For other records, you will usually see a much larger amount of information. Clicking the "Referenced By" tab at the bottom will also tell you about all the places where other records use the global variable in some way.

If you don't want to download third-party software, you can instead use the official Creation Kit (install via Steam under "Tools" for the original Skyrim, or from the Bethesda Launcher for the Special Edition). It also organizes data into categories and records. You'll find the list of global variables under Miscellaneous / Global. Unfortunately, running the CK is a bit tricky for multiple reasons:

1. It won't let you load multiple files.
2. It won't let you load DLC, because that requires loading both the DLC file and Skyrim.esm.
3. It crashes if you look at it funny.
4. Depending on your setup, various bits of functionality might be broken (particularly related to Papyrus scripting). You probably don't need to care about this just to look at the list of globals.

These problems are fixable; see particularly [this mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/99796) and [this thread](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/7023466-papyrus-wont-compile-anything-heres-the-probable-fix/) on Nexusmods. In short, you need to fiddle around with skyrimeditor.ini because its default values are (in many places) incorrect or otherwise problematic.

Answer (score 1):

`SetConsoleOutputFilename` or `scof` used to work in the old Fallout games. In Skyrim LE/SE the method is defined, but the implementation does not do anything.

There is a mod for the old Skyrim LE that logs the console output to a file. It is called [ConSkrybe](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/19630/) on the Nexus mods. It requires SKSE but it has not been updated in a while.

**EDIT**

There is a Skyrim SE mod called [Console Commands Extender](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/28210). This adds output redirection functionality for piping console output to a text file, clearing the console, and setting perk points. You can view the full [Read Me](https://github.com/Ryan-rsm-McKenzie/CCExtender/blob/master/README.md)